# Any reason to get a table/countertop thicker than 1.5"?

Tags: table

I am looking at getting a butcher block table top to construct a desk. The maker offers four standard thicknesses: 1.5", 1.75", 2.25", and 3".

I currently use a 1.5" oak butcher block desk table and it is very rigid, I can stand on it (200 pounds) and it does not bend.

So, why would I need a table any thicker than this? Is it purely for looks, or is there some practical reason?

Answer (score 4):

Appearance and longevity. You can plane down the 3" one quite a few times, but it seems unlikely you'd be using cleavers on your desk. You might want to weigh the price difference between 6/4 and 7/4 against the ability to sand stains and dings out of the thicker one though. That extra quarter inch may add decades of life to the desk in the long run.

Comment: Good answer, but the OP needs to consider whether he's likely to ever sand/plane his desk. (It also depends on the finish.)